# Select values in arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of the same length:

```
 x = [2,3,6,100,2,3,5,8,100,100,5]
 y = [2,3,4,5,5,5,2,1,0,2,4]
```

I selected the position where x==100 in this way:

How is possible to have the value of y where x==100? (that is y=5,0,2)?
I tried in this way:

```
 x100=np.where(x==100)
 y100=y[x100]
```

but it doesn't give me the values I want. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x and y should be numpy arrays:

```
x = np.array([2,3,6,100,2,3,5,8,100,100,5])
y = np.array([2,3,4,5,5,5,2,1,0,2,4])
```

Then your code should work as you expect.

Comment: +1 should be accepted answer (the question specifically said `numpy`)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine when *actually using `numpy` arrays*. You can also write it more succinctly like so.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([2,3,6,100,2,3,5,8,100,100,5])
>>> y = np.array([2,3,4,5,5,5,2,1,0,2,4])
>>> y[x == 100]
array([5, 0, 2])
```

Comment: +1 That is also a conceptually different way of doing things: boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
[b for (a,b) in zip(x,y) if a==100]
```

or

```
itertools.compress(y, [a==100 for a in x])
```

Comment: @ely This is not a numpy solution, by using this code you are reintroducing python overhead to your numpy code. See the answer by PeterCollingridge.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over both and check for 100:

```
x = [2,3,6,100,2,3,5,8,100,100,5]
y = [2,3,4,5,5,5,2,1,0,2,4]
for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
    if xi == 100:
        print(yi)
```

Prints:

```
5
0 
2
```

Or as list comprehension:

```
>>> [yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y) if xi == 100]
[5, 0, 2]
```